# Samsung Health has ads?

Tags: samsung

I never noticed it before, but there is an ad in the top of Samsung Health.
Screenshot below.

Can I turn it off?

I paid for the phone and I do not expect core apps to contain ads.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Yes, it has ads, despite their denial (top of search list). It's been going on from last two years. See [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=Samsung+health+shows+ads&oq=Samsung+health+shows+ads&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160.14225j0j7&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)